# referring to textfields in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I've looked up how I can do this and nothing seems to work.
Trying to use the i in the loop to refer to all my textfields and set them.
Suppose my textfields are named textField0, textField1, textfield2, etc. 
Something like:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++)
{
  parent.child.getChildByName("textField" + i).text = stringArray[i];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error when you execute that or only do not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your hierarchy looks like this

```
0: root:MainTimeline ¬
    0: Background:Shape
    1: textField1:TextField
    2: textField2:TextField
    3: myClip:MovieClip
    4: textField3:TextField
```

We've got some "noise" in the list, so a straight-up iteration over all those might not be the best way.  We could, and place an if statement that tests the name of the object, or its object type, or we could create a manual list of pointers to each of these TextFields.  In that scenario, each textfield could hypothetically exist in any nested container.  It depends on what you have set up.

In the example you gave above, you're referencing an object literally called "child", which would mean your hierarchy might look like this...

```
0: root:MainTimeline ¬
    0: child:MovieClip ¬
        0: textField1:TextField
        1: textField2:TextField
        2: textField3:TextField
    1: myClip:MovieClip // <- assuming that this is the class your code is coming from
```

So, the logic you have is that we go up a level with an implicit `this` reference (`this.parent == parent`), and then down to our container named `child`, and iterate over its children (*note: I suspect this is not the case, and part of the reason its failing*).

Assuming the same hierarchy, I might rewrite it this way:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < parent.child.numChildren; i++) {
    var txt:TextField = parent.child.getChildAt(i);
    txt.text = stringArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't used getChildAt() yet. I still would really need to use getChildByName() because i have many text fields on the same level. I'm getting 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.text:TextField when using getChildByName(). Any reason why this would be?